# Which button form is better from a user experience perspective? Rounded or Boxed?

Tags: buttons, web-app, responsive-design

Could either be confused as labels?   Any other criteria to consider?

[image: rounded]
[image: boxed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, roundness of buttons comes from the [Contour Bias](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0028393207001042) concept:

> Contour Bias is a well-studied theory that shows that humans prefer
>   rounded objects and choices over angled ones. The more angled, the
>   more that human brains reacted with activity in the brain associated
>   with fear and flight.

**in theory**, your 50% rounded button should work better, and there are many studies that prove this, but you also need to consider other elements like color, placement, z-index, 3d aspect and such. And then, of course, test!

Just for fun, take a look at [The Button Test](https://medium.com/@hemeon/the-button-test-77eb4f9a439d). I won't spoil the fun, but you'll notice the only sharp buttons are for a company that arguably created one of the biggest UX mishaps of all times

Also, take a look at [this article](http://www.paulolyslager.com/call-to-action-buttons-shape-size/) to get some in-depth info on the subject